# spring-data-mongodb GroupOperation question

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

i have data in mongodb，just like

```
{
    "name":"test1",
    "receivedDate":"2021-05-18 00:00:52",
}
{
    "name":"test2",
    "receivedDate":"2021-05-18 00:00:52",
}
{
    "name":"test3",
    "receivedDate":"2021-05-18 00:00:52",
}
{
    "name":"test4",
    "receivedDate":"2021-05-18 00:00:52",
}
```

I want to find data with format like:

```
{
    "name":["test1","test2","test3","test4"],
}
```

When I use the following code, it can run

`GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group().push("name").as("name");`

And result like

```
[
    {
        "_id": null,
        "name": [
            "test1",
            "test2",
            "test3",
            "test4",
            "test4"
        ]
    }
]
```

But when I use another code

```
     GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group();
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
            group.push(params[i]).as(params[i]);
        }
```

it get bad result

```
[
    {
        "_id": null
    }
]
```

what should i do?

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB `$group` operator does not allow filtering (only [accumulator operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#std-label-accumulators-group)).

Your second code is trying do something like this:

```
{
  $group:{
    _id:null,
    test1:{
      $push:"$test1"
    },
    test2:{
      $push:"$test2"
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

and you get the wrong result

**Solution:** Filter before grouping ([MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pwUn2ypjtqM))

```
MatchOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("name").in(Arrays.asList(params)))
GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group().push("name").as("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I should use this code

```
group = group.push(params[i]).as(params[i]);
```